# jquery how to refresh the table without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i created a table with the help of kendoGrid data table plugin in which i perform a delete after the delete table sholud get reload and do not the show the deleted user but table doesnot reload and still showing the user in table when i refresh the page the user details will be gone i have tired the following code but it is not working 
Note:delete operation is working properly

```
<head>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#example").dataTable();
        })
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#example").kendoGrid({dataSource: {
                    pageSize: 10
                },
                editable: "popup",
                sortable: true,
                filterable: {
                    extra: false,
                    operators: {
                        string: {
                            contains: "Contains",
                            startswith: "Starts with"
                        }
                    }
                },
                pageable: true,
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        function deleteuser(obj) {
            var uid = obj.id;
            var uname = obj.name;
            if (confirm("This user '" + uname + "' maybe using some other events, Are you sure to delete this user?")) {


                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    //alert(xmlhttp.responseText.trim());
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        //alert(xmlhttp.responseText.trim());
                        if (xmlhttp.responseText.trim() == 'deleted') {
                            alert('This user "' + uname + '" succesfully deleted');
$('#example').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                        } else
                            alert('Error : user cannot deleted');

                    }
                }
                var url = "deleteuser.php?id=" + uid;
                xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
                xmlhttp.send();

            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <table id="example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Action</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Username</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT *  from registration";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="<?php echo $row['user_id'] ?>" onClick="deleteuser(this);" name="<?php echo $row['first_name'] ?>" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['first_name'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['user_name'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>

                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

deleteuser.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    include("../model/functions.php");
    $table = "registration";
    $condition = "user_id=" . $id . "";
    $delete = Deletedata($table, $condition);

    if ($delete === TRUE) {
        echo'deleted';
    } else {
        echo 'not deleted';
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are not using a datasource with your Kendo Grid, so there is nothing to refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not be able to update the table data as is because you have not defined where the table gets the data.  The can either refresh the entire page, or create a `datasource` with a `transport` & `url` that you can use to get the data.

When you populate the table server side:

```
<tbody>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT *  from registration";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="<?php echo $row['user_id'] ?>" onClick="deleteuser(this);" name="<?php echo $row['first_name'] ?>" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['first_name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['user_name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>

            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

There is nothing for the table to refresh.

You need to add a source of data for the table to get the data from.

Ordinarily, I define the datasource for the grid separate from the grid definition itself.

As an example:

```
var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "someurl/to/my/data"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: { id: "user_id" }
    }
});
```

Then you can define your table something like this:

```
var jgrid = $("#example").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
        {
            field: "first_name",
            title: "First Name"
        },
        {
            field: "user_name",
            title: "User Name",
        },
        {
            field: "email",
            title: "Email"
        }
    ],
    dataSource: gridDataSource
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
$('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').refresh();
```